# Android Google Maps API v2 - Requires permission that it already has

Tags: android, google-maps

I've seen a lot of questions posted similar to this but none have helped me so far. I'm getting an error from LogCat that tells me I require a permission to be added to my manifest file. However the permission it's asking me to add is already there. Thanks in advance for any help.

**Manifest**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.bloomu.huskies.tsc71523.skatespot"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <permission android:name="edu.bloomu.huskies.tsc71523.skatelogger.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="edu.bloomu.huskies.tsc71523.skatelogger.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permisson.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-feature 
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="edu.bloomu.huskies.tsc71523.skatelogger.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="edit"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LogCat Error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior: 
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misspelled **permission**

`<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permisson.READ_GSERVICES"/>`

you are missing an `i` after the `s`, before the `o`.

Comment: You know, I specifically checked to see if I just made a spelling mistake at least a dozen times. Haha, thanks anyway.

Comment: Keep in mind that everything in your AndroidManifest.xml is *public*. Every manifest can be read by apps running on stock (non-rooted) devices without requesting any permissions. The maps API key is a public key so there's no need to hide it here on SO. Besides, it's still visible if you look at the edit history for the original question.

Answer (score 3):

use the following code in androidmainfest.xml file

```
 <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="xx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="xx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: You forgot to xxxx-ify `<uses-permission android:name="qa.ooredoo.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />` ;)

Answer (score 0):

your package name is wrong try to correct it

> <uses-permission android:name="edu.bloomu.huskies.tsc71523.skatelogger.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

the correct one is

> <uses-permission android:name="edu.bloomu.huskies.tsc71523.skatespot.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

and even try to add the **gps permission**

> <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>