# Google map v2.0 wont work and app crashes

Tags: android, google-maps, crash

I am working on a map app. It's working for me on SDK 16 but the problem was I need to expand it on sdk 8 and my app crashes. This is my whole code for sdk 16 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193272/my-google-map-v2-test-apps-crashes)

i added support-library-v4 as externar JAR to project. i also added google-play-service-lib as library. but nothing works

I changed  `Activity` to `FragmentActivity`
and also used

```
 googleMap =   ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

instead of

```
googleMap =   ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

I had many problems but finally solved it on sdk 16. I need to use that in sdk 8 but app crashes and doesn't work.

plz help me on this.

this is my manifest:

```
         <permission
        android:name="com.ariagostar.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />



    <uses-permission android:name="com.ariagostar.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/mahdi_theme"
        android:name=".G"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
            >

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">



        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LocationsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >


        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AIDSActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           ></activity>
        <activity android:name=".AboutActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".CureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           ></activity>
        <activity android:name=".EllatActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            ></activity>
        <activity android:name=".InfectedActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            ></activity>
        <activity android:name=".QuestionActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >




        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SeirActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".PreventionActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".TashdidActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".AboutUsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".OtherProductActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MapActivity"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_main">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>



      <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my actual key" />

         <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>
```

and this is my map activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;


public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {



         private GoogleMap googleMap;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.map_form);
            try {
                Log.i("LOG", "map test 1");
                // Loading map
                initilizeMap();
                Log.i("LOG", "map test 2");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                 Log.e("LOG", "I got an error", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    double latitude =20.002 ;
                    double longitude = 3.399;

                    // create marker
                    //MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");

                    // adding marker
                    //googleMap.addMarker(marker);

                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                            new LatLng(37.385044, 78.486671)).zoom(12).build();

                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        private void initilizeMap() {
            if (googleMap == null) {

                //googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

                //googleMap =   ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                //googleMap =   ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                googleMap =   ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


                // check if map is created successfully or not
                if (googleMap == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            initilizeMap();
            super.onResume();
        }


}
```

and this is my map_form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

logcat:

```
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706): I got an error
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706):    at com.ariagostar.hiv.MapActivity.initilizeMap(MapActivity.java:76)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706):    at com.ariagostar.hiv.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:32)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/LOG(4706):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.ariagostar.hiv/com.ariagostar.hiv.MapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2929)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2958)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at com.ariagostar.hiv.MapActivity.initilizeMap(MapActivity.java:76)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at com.ariagostar.hiv.MapActivity.onResume(MapActivity.java:90)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1209)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5450)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2919)
12-13 11:09:51.957: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: Where is your error ?

Comment: @GrIsHu: in emulator it says that:  INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY   and cancels the istalation. in my real device "unfortunately ... has stoped"

Comment: @Kenji Google Maps API V2 does not work on emulator, at all.

Comment: so what i should do? this code worked on SDK 16 and it's still installed on my dev. but have crashes on SDK 8 :(

Comment: see the following link for help you in Google Map
[Google Map][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464136/android-google-maps-api-v2-requires-permission-that-it-already-has/20464609#20464609

Comment: as you can see in my manifest i dont think the problem is from permissions. but any way i add all that permissions you told me. but still crashesh

Comment: No crash log added how one will identify your problem ?

Comment: @GrIsHu: you right. i added the log.

Comment: In your `onResume()` method write the `super.onResume();` and then write ` initilizeMap();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally solved the problem. it was just because of using

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

and should use this one:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

and the apps works correctly

Answer (score 1):

The MapFragment or SupportMapFragment is supported only after API Level 12. It is recommended to use the SupportMapFragment instead.

The Fragment class is not available until API Level 11. and you are targeting API Level 8 which is not supporting Fragment. and thats why i think you are getting the error like below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
```

Comment: i dont used MapFragment . i just used SupportMapFragment and app wont work, i'll upgrade my question with whole code.

Comment: i mentioned below line that fragment class is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `Google Play Services` in project.

Check whether you have already downloaded Google Play Services in `Android SDK Manager`

For more information [Check this example](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

Comment: i added support-library-v4 as externar JAR to project. i also added google-play-service-lib as library. but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

As you error indicates `INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY and cancels the istalation. in my real device "unfortunately ... has stoped"` and as you are using the `SupportMapFragment` and its available in supportv4 library so are supposed to add the `support-library-v4` in your   project to support the map fragment below the API12.

Change your `onResume()` as below:

```
   @Override
    protected void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
         initilizeMap();
    }
```

Comment: i added support-library-v4 as externar JAR to project. i also added google-play-service-lib as library. but nothing works

Comment: thank you. but i finally solved the problem. it was because of map_form